# Присвоить значение элементу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть переменная:

```
var a = "someval";
```

Создаем блок с классом (переменная a).

```
$("#id").append('<div class="' + a + '"></div>');
```

Так как div с классом someval создается динамически, возникает вопрос:
как потом можно осуществить такое действие?

```
$(".someval").append("<p>Text...</p>");
```

Comment: Вот скажите. какое отношение заголовок имеет к вопросу?

Comment: _как потом можно осуществить такое действие?_ - очевидно надо просто вызвать этот код после добавления

Comment: Очевидно... Но ничего не получается. В чем может быть причина? Может потому что имя класса создается динамически?

Comment: _Очевидно... Но ничего не получается._ - значит ты вызываешь неправильно. Приведенный код вполне рабочий

Comment: а, ну да, обычная опечатка. Посмотри строку c div, которой ты делаешь append сначала, не хватает закрывающей `>`

Comment: Этот код для примера. Спасибо, Grundy, буду разбираться. Зато теперь знаю что код должен работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все прекрасно работает.

```js
var a = "someval";

$("#id").append('<div class="' + a + '" > </div>');

$(".someval").append("<p>Text...</p>");
```

```css
.someval{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="id"> </div>
```